# Root with bolzano theorem

Tags: roots

Given this equation  $a\cos{x}+b=x$ with $a,b>0$ how to prove that there is at least one root between $(0,a+b]$ ?
For $x=0$ its $a+b$ which is >0
For $x=a+b$  its $a\cos(a+b) -a=a(\cos(a+b)-1)\leq0$
The problem here is that it is less than equal not less equal. Any idea what should I do ?

Comment: Why is that a problem? If it's equal to $0$, then there's your root.

Comment: cause theory has < . it makes sense but formally not

Comment: So split into cases. If it equals $0$, solve the problem by hand; if it doesn't equal $0$, use the theory.